# jquery :ibegins("xyz") selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap selectpicker, there for livesearch

```
$searchBase.not(':ibegins("search keyword")');
```

is being used.
What exactly ibegins do in selector and how it searches inside elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like ibegins is a case-insensitive selector. It transforms the search term and the search text to all uppercase and then performs the search. You can see the code for that [here at line 202](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/blob/770f3118df52be9fbf529a7fcfa8a00e3bae28d0/docs/docs/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js).

Comment: Yes you are right it is case-insensitive search, but i am confused that to which data it is targeting.
`<
<ul>
<li>Data</li>
<li>Data 2</li>
<li>Data 3</li>
<li>Data 4</li>
</ul>
>`
above is the template and simply running the jquery filter selector with ibegins('Data') will search the li with Data inside it. It seems like query searches inside the <li> tag but not sure about it. if it does so then what is the reliability of this selector.

Comment: @NirajRaskoti I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you link to where you found this code/what you're referring to for context?

Comment: got the answer, actually bootstrap selectpicker has written custom pseudo ibegins for jquery.
source code
 `< 
$.expr.pseudos.ibegins = function (obj, index, meta) {
    var $obj = $(obj);
    var haystack = ($obj.data('tokens') || $obj.text()).toString().toUpperCase();
    return haystack.startsWith(meta[3].toUpperCase());
  };
>`

Comment: Lol ok I linked to that code in the original answer. Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard CSS pseudo class, so it is likely a custom selector defined by the author of the solution you are using. I would recommend reviewing the source code of Bootstrap SelectPicker for further clues.

Comment: same thing i did in my custom select, there also jquery filters with ibegins so i think this is not specific to bootstrap picker only but to jquery.